# Does use of superlative adjective affect the order of adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, superlatives, adjective-order

According to [an article about adjective order by Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order), the following adjective order is correct:

> a small young man

But is the order the same when you make one of the adjectives superlative?:

> a (the?) smallest young man
>
> a (the?) small youngest man

Or should the order be changed? For example:

> the youngest small man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one of the adjectives is a superlative, *by definition* this implies there are others of the same general type. So *the youngest **small man*** implies there are other small men who aren't so young, and *the smallest **young man*** implies there are other young men who aren't so small. In both cases, the highlighted word pair is "elevated" to the status of a ***known combination*** (because we know there are *other* contextually relevant instances of the same general type). Hence the ***non-superlative*** part of the noun phrase becomes "unbreakable", and must appear ***last.*** The last two words together become a kind of ["compound head noun".](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1199011.pdf)

That's to say - *the small youngest man* and *the young smallest man* are incredibly unlikely sequences, because they would require that the audience be familiar with *the youngest man* or *the smallest man* as meaningful references. Which might occur in a contexts like *the young **top dog***, because "top dog" is a known concept. But there won't be many contexts like that.

For a more obviously "superlative" context...

> *He was a **lucky [fastest loser](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2019/sep/26/iaaf-drop-fastest-loser-world-championships)** in the initial qualifying rounds, but he went on to win the championship*

...where ***fastest loser*** is an established collocation (as defined in the link above), and ***fastest lucky loser*** would be nonsense.